# How to load images in html whose src contain {{}} through webpack 2?

Tags: angular, webpack

I use html-loader to load img in html, and it works well when img's src is invariable.as`<img src='../example.png'>`. BUT my when my write like this:`<img src="../../../assets/images/device_{{key.deviceName}}.png">`, it will be error:`Can't resolve '../../../assets/images/device_{{key.deviceName}}.png' in '/Users/zhangxu/Desktop/LicenseServer/angular/src/app/components/home'`.
this is my webpack.config.js:

```js
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders:['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]',
            },

            {
                test:/\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                exclude: helper.root('src','index.html')

            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helper.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
            },
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                include: helper.root('src', 'app'),
                loader:'raw-loader' 
                                    
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass']
            }
        ],

    },
```

this is my HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let key of devices;let i = index;">
       <div class="device" *ngIf="key.selected && !key.out_select" (click)="cancelSelectDevice(i)">
         <img src="../../../assets/images/device_{{key.deviceName}}.png" width="75">
             
        </div>

</div>
```

How can I solve this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that webpack only packs that files for you that it can resolve during build time. But your image paths are computed during runtime, so webpack can't know what image/images you need.

One dirty way is to import every single image in your javascript files. When you do this, webpack has a chance to know what images you want during compile time.

Probably the cleaner way would be to put these images in an assets folder and let your webserver serve this folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not already find solution. but your cleaner way can help me temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [src] property and concatenate strings and variables'.

```
<img [src]="'../../../assets/images/device' + key.deviceName + '.png'" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still can't work well.

Comment: I think it is right path because when I use `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080` to start a webpack server ,it works well. Now I use angular-cli to pack my file, and it works well. I think I don't figure out the real webpack.